# SQL: How to get the right SUM of two different columns from two different data extensions into one new DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, data, sum

I have the following tables:

[image: Table click and send]

In the third table I want to combine these data with the SUM option in SQL so the total of clicks and Sends are in one field. Like this:

[image: Output table]

I created the following query:

```
SELECT 
SUM(s.Sends) as [Sends],
SUM(c.Click) as [Click],
s.JourneyName
FROM [Plus Tracking Journey Bounce] s
join [Plus Tracking Journey Click] c
on s.JourneyName = c.JourneyName
GROUP BY s.JourneyName, c.JourneyName
```

As a result I got this:

[image: OUtput table2]

It multiplies with 2 because there are two records in each table. I tried a different join but with no results. Is this even possible and if so, what do I miss.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select a.JourneyName
, sum(a.Click) as clicks
, sum(b.Sends) as sends
from 
(select 
JourneyName
, sum(Click) as Click
from [Plus Tracking Journey Click]
group by JourneyName
) a
inner join 
(select 
JourneyName
, sum(Sends) as Sends
from [Plus Tracking Journey Bounce]
group by JourneyName
) b
on a.JourneyName = b.JourneyName
Group by a.JourneyName
```

Comment: If you were to put a little explanation into it instead of just the code, it is more likely to be an accepted answer and to get upvotes. Code only answers do not help people learn what the solution is, only provides them an answer. Think of it as 'You can give a man a fish and feed him for a day or teach a man to fish and feed him for life.'

Comment: Great, this works perfectly. Thank you!